# Edit or disable infowindow with Google Maps Directions

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I need to edit or at least to disable infowindow with Google Maps Directions.[image]

This is my code

```
function calcRoute() {
    marker.setMap(null);

    var infowindow1 = '<div class="venue_map_infowindow"><a class="location" href="javascript:void(0);"><h3>My Position</h3></a></div>';
    var infowindow2 = '<div class="venue_map_infowindow"><a class="location" href="javascript:void(0);"><h3>Your Position</h3></a></div>';;

    var request = {
        origin: myLatLng,
        destination: venue_coords,
        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
    };
    directionsService.route(request, function(result, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(result);
        }
        else {
            window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
        }
    });
    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
}
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working for me:

```
    directionsService.route(request, function(result, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            result.routes[0].legs[0].start_address = window0;
            result.routes[0].legs[0].end_address = window1;
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(result);
        }
        else {
            window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can assign your infoWindow like this:

```
var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
  infoWindow: myInfoWindow,
  map: map
});
```

And you can create editableInfoWindow.
See here.
http://googlemaps.googlermania.com/google_maps_api_v3/en/editable_infowindow.html

---

Another answer is that just disable infoWindow:

```
var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
  suppressInfoWindows: true,
  map: map
});
```

And you can parse the directionResult, then add infoWindows by yourself.
Read this page:
http://googlemaps.googlermania.com/google_maps_api_v3/en/map_example_direction_customicon.html